# Entity Framework Query Items with Id from IEnumerable

Tags: entity-framework, linq

Using Entity Framework Code First I have a DbSet of Customers, each customer has a CustomerId:

```
public class Customer
{
    public int CutomerId {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Customer> Customers {get; set;
}
```

All fairly standard.

Somehow I have selected a large sequence of customerIds as an IEnumerable. I want to query all customers with this customerId, to do some heavy LINQ stuff with the selected customers. So I need something like:

```
IEnumerable<int> customerIdsToProcess = ...
using (var myContext =  new MyDbContext())
{
    IQueryable<Customer> selectedCustomers = myContext.Customers
        .Where(customer => customerIdsToProcess.Contains(customer.customerId);
```

However, using Enumerable.Contains results in a SQL IN statement, which can't be used if the collection is large.

So what to do if you have a collection of Ids and you want to get an IQueryable of elements with that Id?

> **Addition**: After thinking about it, this question is a bit hypothetical. Normally you don't have thousands of Ids locally, unless they are the result of a query and thus representable in an IQueryable. So although it would be nice to know how to do this, I guess I'm doing something wrong if I really would need it.

Comment: What about splitting your list, getting queries according to that lists and then unioning queries?

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<Customer> selectedCustomers = myContext.Customers
    .Where(customer => customerIdsToProcess.Any(x=>x.customerId==customer.customerId));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<int> customerIdsToProcess = ...

using (var myContext =  new MyDbContext())
{
    var selectedCustomers = myContext.Customers
        .Join(customerIdsToProcess,x=>x.CustomerId, y=>y,(x,y)=>x).ToList();
}
```

you can use `Join` to retrieve all customers which have the `CustomerId` in `customerIdsToProcess`

in the above example, you need to call `ToList()`, other wise you cannot use `selectedCustomers` for future manipulation, ouside of `using`.